# Python Named Pipes Behavior

Tags: python, linux, named-pipes, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am primarily a PLC programmer who has been tasked with writing some code to run on a Raspberry Pi2B (Raspbian Wheezy) to grab some data from another process running on the RPi and making that data available on a Modbus TCP (*old* PLC protocol) interface.  I have it working, but am now trying to bulletproof it.  I chose Named Pipes for IPC and therein lies my question.  In my Python (v2.7) example code, If I start my reader, it  opens and goes to the readline command and blocks as expected.  When I go and fire up my writer and choose to open, write, and close the pipe, it does as expected and writes a record to the pipe.  The reader, however, just sits there blocking at the readline command.  When the writer loops back around and asks whether to open the pipe or not, if I choose "y" my reader spits out the record written in the prior loop.  I'm happy that I got my data, but don't understand why "opening" the pipe in the writer causes the reader to grab the data at that time.  I would think that I would see read data after my writer has written the record.  Additionally, I think "closing" the pipe in the Writer code doesn't do anything, because I can open the pipe on the first time through the logic, write a record, and then on the next pass through the logic I can choose not to open the pipe and still successfully write it.

1. What am I missing here?  (rhetorical, sort of)
2. What is the proper way to write to a Named Pipe in a loop?
3. Why does the reader only grab a record after the Writer "opens" the pipe   (whether it was open or not from the previous pass through the loop)?

Thanks in advance and be nice to me...Remember, I'm just an old PLC programmer who has been forced into Python-World!

Writer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s') 
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.debug('Logging has started')

log.debug('DocTest Pipe Writer')
import os, time, sys
PipeName = 'DocTestPipe'

if not os.path.exists(PipeName):
    log.debug('Pipe not present...Creating...')
    os.mkfifo(PipeName, 0777)
    log.debug('Pipe is made')
else:
    log.debug('Pipe already present')
ModbusSeed = 0
while True:
    OpenPipe = raw_input ('Open pipe? y or n')
    if OpenPipe == 'y':
        log.debug('Opening pipe')
        PipeOut = open(PipeName, 'w')
        log.debug('Pipe is open for writing.')
    else:
         log.debug('Chose not to open pipe')   
    DataPipeString = '%05d' % ModbusSeed+','+'%05d' % (ModbusSeed+1)+','+'%05d' % (ModbusSeed+2)+','+ \
        '%05d' % (ModbusSeed+3)+','+'%05d' % (ModbusSeed+4)+','+'%05d' % (ModbusSeed+5)+','+ \
        '%05d' % (ModbusSeed+6)+','+'%05d' % (ModbusSeed+7)+','+'%05d' % (ModbusSeed+8)+','+ \
        '%05d' % (ModbusSeed+9)+'\n'
    print 'Pipe Data to write: '+DataPipeString
    WritePipe=raw_input('Write Pipe? y or n')
    if WritePipe == 'y':
        log.debug('Writing pipe')
        PipeOut.write(DataPipeString)
        log.debug('Pipe is written.')
    ClosePipe = raw_input('Close pipe? y or n')
    if ClosePipe == 'y':
        log.debug('Closing pipe')
        PipeOut.close
        log.debug('Pipe is closed')
    else:
        log.debug('Pipe left open')
    ModbusSeed=ModbusSeed+1
```

Reader:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s') #,filename='DocTestLog')
log = logging.getLogger()
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.debug('Logging has started')
log.debug('Modbus Server started.')

import os, time, sys

PipeName = 'DocTestPipe'
if not os.path.exists(PipeName):
    log.debug('Pipe not present...Creating...')
    os.mkfifo(PipeName, 0777)
    log.debug('Pipe is made')
else:
    log.debug('Pipe already present')

log.debug('Open pipe for reading')
PipeIn = open(PipeName, 'r')
log.debug('Pipe is open for reading')

while True:
    #raw_input('Press any key to read pipe')
    log.debug('Reading Line')
    try:
        PipeString = PipeIn.readline() [:-1]
    except:
        print 'Nothing there'
    #PipeString = PipeIn.read()
    log.debug('PipeString = '+PipeString)
```

Answer (score 1):

After much head scratching, scouring the internet, and trial and error, I have my answer.  The crux of the problem was that when I opened my pipe for writing, I didn't specify a "buffering" argument.  This caused my pipe write to be cached somewhere in a buffer instead of being immediately written to the pipe.  Whenever I "opened" my write pipe, it flushed the buffer to the pipe and my reader then picked it up.  The solution was to add ",0" as an additional argument to my "open" command (PipeOut = open(PipeName, 'w',0) instead of PipeOut = open(PipeName, 'w')), thus setting the buffer size to zero.  Now when I "write" to the pipe, the data goes directly to the pipe and doesn't sit around in limbo until flushed.